# Calling non default template constructor in a Class constructor

Tags: c++, templates

Is it possible in the following example to call the "not default constructor" of class A for every element of mVector within the constructor of class B ?

```
class A {
public:
    A (int n) {/*stuff*/}
};

class B {
public:
    B (): mVector(10) {}  //call A(int n) constructor?

private:
    vector<A> mVector;
};
```

Comment: Sortof `mVector(10, A(10))` will call the copy constructor of A with the object constructed using the non-default constructor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to set all the elements to the same value, there's a [constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) for that

```
mVector(10, 42)  // 10 elements initialised with value 42
```

If you want to set the elements to different values, use list initialisation

```
mVector{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}  // 10 elements with different values
```

Strictly speaking, this doesn't do exactly what you describe; it creates a temporary `T`, and then uses that to copy-initialise each vector element. The effect should be the same, unless your type has weird copy semantics.

Answer (score 0):

You could do one thing here:-

```
B() : mVector(10, A(10))
{
}
```

Or

```
B() : mVector(10, 10)
{
}
```

Both are essentially the same thing. However, former one is more efficient.

Comment: There's no inheritance here, just a member to initialise.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the constructor overload of `std::vector` taking an *element count* and a *value* which for your use case is equivalent to:

```
std::vector(size_type count, const T& value);
```

Use it to initialize the elements with the value type's non default constructor:

```
std::vector<A> mVector(10, A{0}); // 10 elements copy initialized using 'A{0}'.
```

Or when initializing in the initialization list:

```
B() : mVector(10, A{0}) {}
```